# rdlc report - doesn't show new data of DataSet

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc, reportbuilder

I have an rdlc report in VS2017:

I'm facing a very strange problem after I have **renamed** the output fields coming from stored procedure:

I have first modified the stored procedure and renamed the fields, I have refreshed the dataset xsd and I can see the new renamed fields, then in rdlc report I have refreshed the dataset and I can see the new fields...

All its ok till now, but if I run and generate the report, the new renamed fields are empty...

I have tried to delete and create again the dataset... But nothing happens.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the reference of your dataset from RDLC report. Then recompile your project, if you do clean then it is better.
Then again add your modified dataset in RDLC report and bind your fields again. You need to completely remove your reference of dataset from RDLC. Hope this works out and sort out your issue if still it does not resolve your issue then kindly share your code.